# Java code for search Tweets

Tags: java, tweets, tweetsharp

I want to store particular topic's tweets into files.

Here is my code.

```
package twitter4j.examples.search;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLEngineResult.Status;
public class SearchTweets
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws TwitterException
    {
        Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
        twitter.setOAuthConsumer("[a9Ru5GLWVbI1iMfkeAHQ9A]", "[Xs0iSIbGIEZ9XS0y6zACwdjJMLPSOA6p5iAjQQmRAfs]");
        RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
        AccessToken accessToken = "1878852745-4b8qrNloveM43dMnjK2KBMFUIBJj5bwVRig2Wki";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while (null == accessToken)
        {
            System.out.println("Open the following URL and grant access to your account:");
            System.out.println(requestToken.getAuthorizationURL());
            System.out.print("Enter the PIN(if aviailable) or just hit enter.[PIN]:");
            String pin = br.readLine();
            try
            {
                if(pin.length() &gt; 0)
                {
                    accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken, pin);
                }
                else
                {
                    accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken();
                }
            }
            catch (TwitterException te)
            {
                if(401 == te.getStatusCode())
                {
                    System.out.println("Unable to get the access token.");
                }
                else
                {
                    te.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Query query = new Query("source:twitter4j yusukey");
            QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
            for (Status status : result.getTweets())
            {
                System.out.println("@" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + ":" + status.getText());
            }
            //persist to the accessToken for future reference.
            String token = "1878852745-4b8qrNloveM43dMnjK2KBMFUIBJj5bwVRig2Wki";
            String tokenSecret = "1878852745-4b8qrNloveM43dMnjK2KBMFUIBJj5bwVRig2Wki";
            Status status = twitter.updateStatus(args[0]);
            System.out.println("Successfully updated the status to [" + status.getText() + "].");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Error :-

```
Multiple markers at this line

    - TwitterFactory cannot be resolved

    - Twitter cannot be resolved to a type
```

please help me to solved this error because I am doing this type code first time.

Also suggest me any website for this topic (java code storing tweets into file )

Comment: Have you added twitter4j jar file to your classpath?

Comment: yes I added twitter4j jar file

Comment: Is it in your classpath.. ? Double check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incude the following `twitter4j-core-3.0.4.jar` in your classpath..

**Download it from here :**
[twitter4j-core-3.0.4.jar](http://twitter4j.org/archive/twitter4j-3.0.4.zip)